# Winform C# dataGridViev

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Хочу создать статическую переменную ,которая возвращает количество строк в таблице.

Ошибка: `CS0120 Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Person.dataGridView1" требуется ссылка на объект.`

Как исправить ошибку?

```
public static int person_count
{
    get =>dataGridView1.RowCount;
    set
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Не делать свойство статическим. Потому что данные, к которому оно относится являются данными объекта, а не статического класса.

Comment: Кажется, ваша проблема куда глубже, вы случайно не пытаетесь передавать данные между формами? (просто подобные костыли ради таких вещей пилят)

Comment: @Blackmeser Костыль именно для этого)

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит из-за того, что переменная `person_count` статическая, а `dataGridView1` не статический, одним из возможных способов решения является - сделать переменную не статической, то есть

было:`public static int person_count`.

стало:`public int person_count`.

Либо же делать `dataGridView1` статическим, если переменная необходима статической.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Form1 : Form //основная форма
{
   //dataGridView1 в дизайнере
   button_click_createform(sender, arg)
   {
      Form2 f2 = new Form2(dataGridView1);
   }
}

class Form2 : Form //второстепенная форма
{
   DataGridView ref_dataGridView;
   int person_count => ref_dataGridView.RowCount; //вот тут нужные вам данные
   public Form2(DataGridView dataGridView)
   {
      ref_dataGridView = dataGridView;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`person_count` сделайте не статическим:

```
public int person_count
{
    get =>dataGridView1.RowCount;
    set
    {
    }
}
```